# err1005 : Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

First of all I know there is many post on this subject on StackOverflow.
I checked to them but none was answering my problem.

Second thing, I'am using a PHPMyAdmin on OVH. So I am not admin, I have no root access. It means someone created the databases for me and give me the login / password to access it.

So here is my problem.
I try to create a table called `matrice_solution`. Here is the default `create table`.

```
CREATE TABLE `matrice_solution` (
  `id_matrice_solution` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `label` varchar(100) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Texte indicatif pour définir la matrice de solution',
  `fk_id_matrice` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Une combinaison de réponse, et donc son identifiant de matrice associé, n''accepte qu''une seule solution',
  `fk_id_solution` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Une matrice de solution peut pointer soit vers une solution, soit vers une étape',
  `fk_id_nextstep` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Une matrice de solution peut pointer soit vers une solution, soit vers une étape',
  `fk_id_step` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Une matrice de solution appartient a une étape',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_matrice_solution`),
  UNIQUE KEY `fk_id_matricesolution_UNIQUE` (`fk_id_solution`,`fk_id_matrice`),
  KEY `fk_matricesolution_matrice_idx` (`fk_id_matrice`),
  KEY `fk_matricesolution_solution_idx` (`fk_id_solution`),
  KEY `fk_matricesolution_nextstep_idx` (`fk_id_nextstep`),
  KEY `fk_matricesolution_step_idx` (`fk_id_step`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_matricesolution_matrice` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_id_matrice`) REFERENCES `matrice` (`id_matrice`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_matricesolution_nextstep` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_id_nextstep`) REFERENCES `step` (`id_step`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_matricesolution_solution` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_id_solution`) REFERENCES `solution` (`id_solution`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_matricesolution_step` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_id_step`) REFERENCES `step` (`id_step`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

For informations, all other tables referenced by Foreign keys have already been created.

But when I try to create this table I have the famous error : `mysql #1005 - Can't create table` and in details `Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys`.

The real problem is that if I try to create this table with the simpliest way, I didnt works too. Same problem :

```
CREATE TABLE `matrice_solution` (
  `id_matrice_solution` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `label` varchar(100) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Texte indicatif pour définir la matrice de solution',
  `fk_id_matrice` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Une combinaison de réponse, et donc son identifiant de matrice associé, n''accepte qu''une seule solution',
  `fk_id_solution` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Une matrice de solution peut pointer soit vers une solution, soit vers une étape',
  `fk_id_nextstep` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Une matrice de solution peut pointer soit vers une solution, soit vers une étape',
  `fk_id_step` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Une matrice de solution appartient a une étape'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The fact is that I already `create` this table once, but I miss named it using `id_matrice_solution` instead of `matrice_solution`. PHPMyAdmin didnt let met use `RENAME TABLE`. Thats why I dropped it and tried to recreate it. With no success. I imagine there is some references which still exists, maybe in `information_schema`, but I didnt found anything.

I surely missed something.

Some help would be really nice. I'm on this problem for 2 hours, my brain 'll finish to explode and my computer too if its continue ;)

EDIT :

Even this doesnt work :

```
CREATE TABLE `matrice_solution` (
  `id_matrice_solution` int(11) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Since you can't rename the table, make sure you have dropped it. That might be the reason why you can't create it again. The second rule, when dealing with foreign keys - the column you *reference* must be exactly the **same** as the column that *references* it. This means if *referenced* column is `UNSIGNED INT` then the one that references it must be `UNSIGNED INT` as well - the data type and data length must match, otherwise you get the famous error.

Comment: If I do a `SHOW TABLES`,  `matrice_solution` doesnt appears. I can create table `matrice_solution` as MyISAM but not as InnoDB. Column types are ok because those create informations are a dump of the existing DB in my local environnement.

Comment: Could it be that your host simply doesn't have InnoDB engine support?

Comment: No, my 10 other tables are using InnoDB and have been successfully created.

Comment: Well, something's definitely wrong there. I must admit I've never encountered such a situation. Sadly, I've no advice to help you out but I will keep an eye on this question since the solution interests me. Good luck fixing it!

Comment: No solution found finally. I think the only way to clean everything was to drop the database but I have no privileges for that. My "solution" was to name differently the table ... such a poor solution ... Thx for the help.

Comment: Something's extremely fishy with that host of yours.. I must admit I haven't had such an issue which is why I was interested. I'm sad to hear you had to use a sub-optimal solution :/ but sometimes we just don't have a choice.